# "Minimum supported Gradle version is 4.4" error started today; no code changes

Tags: android, gradle

Today, multiple developers on my team started seeing this error when they attempt to run any Gradle task.

```
* Where:
Build file 'C:\dev\src\my_app_name\app\build.gradle' line: 1

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.android.application']
   > Minimum supported Gradle version is 4.4. Current version is 4.1. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in C:\dev\src\my_app_name\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-4.4-all.zip
```

Absolutely no code or config changes were made; Gradle builds just suddenly started to fail. Anyone know why this would happen? My best guess is that a plugin with a dependency on a specific version of Gradle auto-updated itself, but I'm not sure how to figure out which one it is. The line number would suggest that it was the `com.application.plugin` plugin itself.

I am aware that Android Studio updates often require a corresponding upgrade to Gradle, but nobody on my team updated Android Studio. And, according to the Android-Studio-Gradle [version compatibility table](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin.html#updating-gradle), Gradle 4.1 should still work fine with Android Studio 3.0.1, which is what I have been running for some time.

We recently started using Kotlin, and I thought that might be part of the problem, but completely removing everything related to Kotlin didn't help.

I have tried deleting the Gradle `caches/` directory, running `./gradlew cleanBuildCache`, deleting our project's `build/` directories, killing Gradle daemons via `./gradlew --stop`, and rebooting -- all to no avail.

I also tried upgrading to Gradle 4.4, but that resulted in a "CIRCULAR REFERENCE" NullPointerException error during DexMergerTransform ([separate issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48971092/315702)), for reasons that are entirely unclear to me. I'd like to be able to force my environment to NOT take on a Gradle 4.4 dependency right now... but I don't know what suddenly triggered this dependency.

Comment: Did you specify fixed versions for all used plugins?

Comment: We specify versions for all libraries, but have never had to worry about plugin versions. I'm now going through the process of figuring out where I can find version release history for each plugin.

Comment: The more I think about it, the more it seems that the version of Gradle specified in gradle-wrapper.properties should limit which plugin versions are used, when no plugin versions are specified. It doesn't seem like applying a plugin should force a Gradle upgrade. Maybe I'm on a wild goose chase with plugin versions.

Comment: Plugins are much like external libraries (just used during the build instead of included into the product). To get full control over the build always specify exact versions. Due to third party plugins Gradle cannot know beforehand which versions are compatible. It would have to fetch several versions of a certain plugin to find out a compatible version. This would be very inefficient.

Comment: After doing more digging, I discovered that the only plugin for which we don't specify exact version in dependencies is butterknife. For that, we have "com.jakewharton:butterknife-gradle-plugin:9.0.0-SNAPSHOT", which seems suspect. Will try an official release version of that plugin tomorrow.

Comment: all I can see are two self-answered questions for one and the same issue.

Comment: @MartinZeitler, it's two separate issues with the same solution. Search terms for each issue are separate, and of the two this is the one that's more likely to have lasting relevance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem turned out to be that we were using a non-specific version of a plugin. When a change was made to the plugin, the new version was downloaded to our dev environments, and it introduced a dependency on a version of Gradle higher than the one we were using.

In our case, this was the culprit:

`classpath 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-gradle-plugin:9.0.0-SNAPSHOT'`

Downgrading to version 8.5.1 of the Butterknife plugin eliminated the dependency on Gradle 4.4.

You also have the option of linking to a specific pre-release "nightly" version. However, this is less than ideal, since these bits don't remain available for long, and you might want to download a build and keep it in your local lib. For example:

`classpath 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-gradle-plugin:9.0.0-20180727.012508-40'`

Answer (score 0):

instead of down-grading, one could provide the plugin in version `9.0.0` with the expect version of Gradle, by editing the file `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`; for example:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.5-all.zip
```

version `4.5` works stable and might not create the `circular reference`, alike `4.4` does. and when looking at the [issues](https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue%20gradle) tracker on GitHub, this Gradle plugin might add more problems, than it would serve any real purpose - because the Android SDK already supports two-way data-binding.

currently the [artifacts](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.jakewharton/butterknife-gradle-plugin) still list `8.8.1` as the latest version; while a `SNAPSHOT` is barely stable... that nothing happend there since over a year, hints for that this project might have been abandoned... most likely because of [Architecture Components](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/architecture) data-binding.

Comment: Upgrading the Gradle version is the obvious choice, but the point of this issue was that we were not in a position to upgrade Gradle, and needed to understand where the unwanted dependency was coming from.

Comment: @markproxy the mere problem, which leads to such issues, is when people try to be at the bleeding edge of technology, which may or may not be half-baked; about the same goes for the canary channel of Android Studio and also the current release candidate support libraries.